# How to Get JSON of each row of the Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am facing an issue getting the JSON of each row.
I have the table which contains OrderId and TotalCost.
I need to get the table data for OrderID and TotalCost with JsonData.

Can someone please help me with this, How i can write the query which give me the json data of each row of the table.

```
  CREATE TABLE tblOrder ( [Orderid] int, [TotalCost] decimal(18,2) )
GO

INSERT INTO tblOrder ([Orderid], [TotalCost])
VALUES
( 1, 1770.00 ), 
( 2, 200.00 ), 
( 3, 100.00 ), 
( 4, 200.00 ), 
( 5, 50.00 )
Go
SELECT * FROM tblOrder
```

The is the Table I have which contains below Data

[image: the Table name Order]

and the desire output I need is

[image]

Comment: Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data, like you have been asked to on previous questions.

Comment: I have put the query now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be as simple as this:

```
SELECT * 
      ,JSONData =  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )
 FROM tblOrder A
```

**Note the alias A and A.***

Results

[image]

Comment: Thank for Quick Reply. I try with many complex logic but not reach the solution, 
your simple way solve my issue.

Comment: @preeti I just noticed you tagged 2012.   If this is true, there is a similar approach using XML